# Where are the C++ implementations of the advanced ellipse detection algorithms?

Tags: image, opencv, pattern-matching, hough-transform

I'm a novice in the field of ellipse detection/extraction. But I know this topic has a long history. Although there are tons of papers addressing ellipse detection, I can hardly find any C++ implementations of these advanced algorithms such as Straight Line HT (SLHT), Fast Ellipse Hough Transform (FEHT), and Randomized HT (RHT). I'm curious Why the researchers don't put their code online such that more people can benefit from them? Can anyone kindly tell me where I can find any of the C++ implementations? Thanks.

(PS: I'm familiar with OpenCV. I know OpenCV has few implementations such as fitEllipse and HoughCircle.)

Comment: I think I should look at something like called Generalized Hough transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of image processing research is done in Matlab, there are generally implementations available in that language. The reason you don't see any C++ implementations is because they would be much more about the details of implementation (memory management, performance, etc) rather than the actual algorithm; Matlab is much more succinct about this.

If you really want to get to learn about image processing algorithms, you'll probably want to learn to read Matlab code.

Comment: Thanks. After asking some of my friends, I got the same answer. Using matlab to test algos is totally understandable. In fact, I use matlab on a daily basis. Nowadays, OpenCV is quite popular. But if the advanced algos can be integrated in OpenCV, that would be the best for people like me. Otherwise, we need to read matlab code and covert into C++ code by ourselves.

Comment: I know your frustration. It would be great if the algorithms were production quality and usable in many different circumstances. If you look at some of the implementations in OpenCV though, you can see how complicated that is. In my experience those implementations look nothing like the actual algorithm, because they're concerned with making it fast. Most researchers simply don't have the time to do that.